# Were the Twelve Kingdoms/Juuni Kokuki novels ever finished?

Tags: the-twelve-kingdoms

Twelve Kingdoms/Juuni Kokuki was an anime that I really loved and I was very disappointed when it got cancelled, also because it had some unfinished story arcs like the Gyousou/Taiki arc.

Since there are translations available of the novels (both official and unofficial), I have pondered about reading those. However, I always get the impression that though the novels do continue the story arcs in the anime (and more), they were never finished either, so if you were to read them you'd still be left with unfinished arcs (though perhaps ones different from the anime). While searching the internet, I can't seem to find a definitive answer unfortunately, the sources I find either do not mention anything about whether the novels were finished, or to me seem vague about it at best and mostly talk about that not all novels were translated.

Does anybody know whether the (original Japanese) novels have finished or has anybody read all the novels and can give the answer?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article for the series, it looks like it has, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe the main story has concluded, the subsequent volumes, *The Dream of Prosperity* and *The Birds of Hisho* (most recently in 2013), are collected short stories and previous unpublished stories set in various kingdoms. Kodansha USA currently holds the right for the series in the US, since the collapse of Tokyopop, with only 8 volumes of the original Japanese release having been published (Tokyopop merged the first 8 volumes into 4).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! From more searching I came across http://12ktp.inspirelight.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=499 where when I read the replies it seems to confirm my impression that though the Taiki/Gyousou story line was continued in the books, it was never concluded. I don't know though whether there are any other unfinished story lines or if that's the only one that was only partially finished.